# Ajax starts too late... Really inconvenient

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this problem with AJAX. I run the code and the ajaxString is undefined when the code is printed even though the Ajax code is pretty much called before the return statement. When I try to retrieve AJAX after the HTML generation and printing, the AJAX is defined so it makes me think that the return is called before AJAX gets the chance to finish. Any way around this? Here is my current code:

```
var ajaxHTML;
function runCode(str) {
    if (str == 'SubmitB' || str == 'SubmitC' || str == 'SubmitD') {
        generateHTML(str);
    }
    else {
    $('#Holder1').html("");
    $('#Holder2').html("");
    $("#container_demo").fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#menu_container").html(generateHTML(str))},500);
    $("#container_demo").fadeIn(500);
    }
}
function generateHTML(source){
if (source =='d') {
          return makeSchoolComboBox() + "Please Select a Level: <select id='selectedLevel'><option value='level1'>l1</option><option value='level2'>l2</option><option value='level3'>l3</option><option value='level4'>l4</option></select><br> <button id = 'r' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Go back</button><button id = 'SubmitD' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Submit</button>";
    }
function makeSchoolComboBox() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'phpQueries.php?q=fill_school_list',
            success: function (data) {
                ajaxHTML = data;
            }
        });
        return ajaxHTML;
}
```

Comment: Try as ajax param `async: true` or call the `makeSchoolComboBox()` as a callback to `runCode()`

Comment: You know the A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous right? The data isn't being returned in time for the `return` to work properly. You should probably use a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AJAX is asynchronous, you can't call it and then return straight after as the call is still taking place.  You need to populate the menu container in the success callback, like this...

```
function runCode(str) {
    if (str == 'SubmitB' || str == 'SubmitC' || str == 'SubmitD') {
        generateHTML(str);
    }
    else {
        $('#Holder1').html("");
        $('#Holder2').html("");
        $("#container_demo").fadeOut(500);
        makeSchoolComboBox();
    }
}

function makeSchoolComboBox() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'phpQueries.php?q=fill_school_list',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#menu_container").html(data  + "Please Select a Level: " +
                "<select id='selectedLevel'>" +
                "<option value='level1'>l1</option>" +
                "<option value='level2'>l2</option>" +
                "<option value='level3'>l3</option>" +
                "<option value='level4'>l4</option>" +
                "</select><br> <button id = 'r' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Go back</button>" +
                "<button id = 'SubmitD' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Submit</button>").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax query is asynchronous

```
function makeSchoolComboBox(next) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'phpQueries.php?q=fill_school_list',
    success: next
  });
}
```

and run it as

```
makeSchoolComboBox(function(ajaxHTML){
  //manipulations with here
})
```

Or you can pass `async: false` in your `$.ajax`, but all stops while ajax request processed in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the structure you're using (I'd make generateHTML and makeSchoolComboBox into a single function to keep it simple) then you can use promises.

Your code would then become:

```
function generateHTML(source){
if (source =='d') {
          makeSchoolComboBox().then(function(data) {
              return data + "Please Select a Level: <select id='selectedLevel'><option value='level1'>l1</option><option value='level2'>l2</option><option value='level3'>l3</option><option value='level4'>l4</option></select><br> <button id = 'r' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Go back</button><button id = 'SubmitD' onClick='runCode(this.id)'>Submit</button>";
          });
    }
}

function makeSchoolComboBox() {
     var d = new $.Deferred();

     $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 'phpQueries.php?q=fill_school_list',
             success: function(data) {
                 return d.resolve(data);
             }
     });
}
```

Comment: I really want to use your solution but I get this error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Comment: First all `$.ajax` already returns a promise. Second, even if you use the deferred anti pattern, you're using it incorrectly (not returning `d`)

Comment: My bad, code updated.